# Select by datetime range is very slow in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, myisam

I have table `posts` with 6.5M+ records. Each post is represented using fixed length `name`. I use MySQL Community 5.7, SSD disk with around 10K-20K IOPS and 1GB memory, `key-buffer-size` set to 512M (BTW mostly I drive with default MySQL config). I have limited resources therefore I have choosed MyISAM as my storage engine. My benchmarks showed me that in my case MyISAM is faster. Also I don't care about data so much because it can be renewed.

**So, here is my scheme info:**

```
+------------+--------+------------+
| TABLE_NAME | ENGINE | row_format |
+------------+--------+------------+
| posts      | MyISAM | Fixed      |
+------------+--------+------------+

+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | int(11) unsigned    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name                | char(30)            | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| worker_id           | tinyint(4) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| processing_priority | tinyint(4) unsigned | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| last_processed_at   | datetime            | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| scraped_at          | datetime            | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

+-------+------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name            | Seq_in_index | Column_name         | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| posts |          0 | PRIMARY             |            1 | id                  | A         |     6579588 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| posts |          0 | name                |            1 | name                | A         |     6579588 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| posts |          1 | last_processed_at   |            1 | last_processed_at   | A         |     6579588 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| posts |          1 | processing_priority |            1 | processing_priority | A         |           3 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| posts |          1 | worker_id           |            1 | worker_id           | A         |          50 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| posts |          1 | scraped_at          |            1 | scraped_at          | A         |      234985 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

**The query I run:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`worker_id` = 1 AND (last_processed_at >= '2017-11-04 22:20:27.203761')
```

MySQL needs 3676.4ms to execute this query.

**Query explained:**

```
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-----------------------------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys               | key       | key_len | ref   | rows   | filtered | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-----------------------------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | posts | NULL       | ref  | last_processed_at,worker_id | worker_id | 1       | const | 232621 |    37.45 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+------+-----------------------------+-----------+---------+-------+--------+----------+-------------+
```

Do you have any ideas how it can be optimized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a combined key with `worker_id` and `last_processed_at`, replacing the `worker_id` key.

Comment: Some details: currently, MySQL uses only one of `last_processed_at` and `worker_id` on the table `posts`. It gets all rows by `worker_id` using index and then goes through all these rows to compare `last_processed_at` one by one. It takes time. If you create combined index `worker_id` + `last_processed_at`, MySQL will use the second part of the combined index to filter by `last_processed_at` as well as by `worker_id`, so it'll be much-much faster.

See Docs [MySQL 5.7 Multiple-Column Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html)

Comment: Thank you! You helper a lot. I have created index on two columns `worker_id` + `last_processed_at`. Now query needs no more than 10ms. That's 360 times faster.

Comment: @Animir So basically in old case MySQL used index on `worker_id` and then it read `last_processed_at` from the disk to use in conditions, right?

Comment: @yivo almost, it used `worker_id` index to filter data and then went trough all rows in result data set to filter by `last_processed_at`. Data may be stored on disk or in memory, it depends, but index helps to find certain data block, "shift cursor" straight to required data and start select, e.g. if your data has 10 worker ids, and you need to find all data for worker id = 1 by index `worker_id`, MySQL returns block 1 and then filters it by `last_processed_at` row by row. Hope, this helps.

Comment: @Animir Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you are cramped for space:

- `CHAR(30)` for variable length `names` possibly makes your .MYD file 50% bigger than it needs to be if Ascii or latin1, or 3 *times* as big as needed if utf8.
- Don't blindly index every column; that wastes space in the .MYI file.  In particular, `INDEX(processing_priority)` is probably never used.

Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and some of the queries to further critique the setup for space.

1GB of RAM with 512MB for `key_buffer` is really bad.  First, the key_buffer is only for caching index blocks (1KB each).  Secondly, you need room for caching data, which the OS does.  Third, you need room for code and other data.  Recommend no more than `key_buffer_size = 50M`.

(As for your actual question, @Turo gives an excellent answer.)  But did you remove the now-redundant `INDEX(worker_id)`?  (That will save about 70MB.)

More on index creation:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql